# Need to disable Particle System as soon as it stops playing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to implement a Flame Thrower. I have setup the Particle System for flame. It is pooled object. It is not the child of the Flame Thrower. When I press the Fire button the particle system starts and when the button is up it stops. But a problem arised that when player is moving the particle system doesn't move . this was solved by adding the below line

```
particles.transform.position = transform.GetChild(0).position;
```

But the I discovered another problem that when rotating the player(This is a 2D sidescroller game) the particles are rotated with it instantly. So when the player changes the direction current particles are stopped and a new particle is activated and played. But now the problem is whenever I change the direction while pressing Fire buttons new objects are created.

The code of my flame thrower is
using UnityEngine;

```
public class FlameThrower : Gun
{
    private ParticleSystem particles;

    private int direction = 0;
    private bool isFiring = false;

    public override void Update()
    {
        if(shoot)
        {
            InitShoot();
        }
        else
        {
            StopFire();
        }
    }

    public override void InitShoot()
    {
        if(!isFiring)
        {
            SelectDirection();
            Fire();
        }

        //Check direction has changed
        if(direction != playerManager.direction)
        {
            StopFire();
        }

        if(particles != null)
        {
            particles.transform.position = transform.GetChild(0).position;
        }
    }

    public override void Fire()
    {
        isFiring = true;
        direction = playerManager.direction;

        InstantiateParticles(weapon.bulletName, transform.GetChild(0).position, rotation);
    }

    public override void SelectDirection()
    {
        if (playerManager.direction == 1)
        {
            rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, -90);
        }
        else if (playerManager.direction == -1)
        {
            rotation = Quaternion.Euler(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, 90);
        }
    }

    public override void InstantiateParticles(string name, Vector3 position, Quaternion rotation)
    {
        GameObject bullet = ObjectPooler.instance.GetObject(name);

        while (bullet == null)
        {
            ObjectPooler.instance.CreateObject(name);
            bullet = ObjectPooler.instance.GetObject(name);
        }

        if (bullet != null)
        {
            particles = bullet.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
            //Set Position and rotation
            bullet.transform.position = position;
            bullet.transform.rotation = rotation;
            bullet.SetActive(true);
            particles.Play();
        }
    }

    private void StopFire()
    {
        if (particles != null)
        {
            isFiring = false;
            particles.Stop();
            if(!particles.isPlaying)
            {
                particles.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                particles = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that in the function StopFire() it checks whether particle is playing or not. If it is not playing it will disable the Gameobject. But it that part doesn't execute since it is checked soon after particles is stopped and it will still be playing. I want this particle system to be disabled as soon as it stops playing

Comment: A gif would be helpful!

Comment: change the `simulation space` of particle system to `world`

Comment: @Bijan That worked. Thanks.

Comment: @Bijan Sounds like that can be expanded to an answer (don't forget to link to the documentation for completeness).

Comment: @Serlite Ok thanks

Comment: @mahir Don't forget to accept an answer if it satisfactorily solves your question - this indicates to other users that your problem has been solved (and also gives you some points, if that's your thing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the particle system is rendering in local space, that's why it rotates with the object.

Change the `Simulation Space` to `World`.

[image]

For the other issue, if you disable the game object then particles which are already emitted will disappear. And if you deactivates them with a delay (using Invoke or similar) then within that delay new particles can be emitted.

The best way to handle this is to stop the emission, not deactivating the game object. You can do this in inspector or via code. `myParticles.emission.enabled`

[image]

Comment: I don't have access to unity docs (banned in my country) it will be appreciated if someone edit and add the required docs

Comment: You included some explanatory screenshots inline, so I think that's probably good enough!

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ParticleSystemControllerWindow : MonoBehaviour
{
ParticleSystem system
{
    get
    {
        if (_CachedSystem == null)
            _CachedSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        return _CachedSystem;
    }
}
private ParticleSystem _CachedSystem;

public Rect windowRect = new Rect(0, 0, 300, 120);

public bool includeChildren = true;

void OnGUI()
{
    windowRect = GUI.Window("ParticleController".GetHashCode(), windowRect, DrawWindowContents, system.name);
}

void DrawWindowContents(int windowId)
{
    if (system)
    {
        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Toggle(system.isPlaying, "Playing");
        GUILayout.Toggle(system.isEmitting, "Emitting");
        GUILayout.Toggle(system.isPaused, "Paused");
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        if (GUILayout.Button("Play"))
            system.Play(includeChildren);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Pause"))
            system.Pause(includeChildren);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Stop Emitting"))
            system.Stop(includeChildren, ParticleSystemStopBehavior.StopEmitting);
        if (GUILayout.Button("Stop & Clear"))
            system.Stop(includeChildren,  ParticleSystemStopBehavior.StopEmittingAndClear);
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

        includeChildren = GUILayout.Toggle(includeChildren, "Include Children");

        GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        GUILayout.Label("Time(" + system.time + ")");
        GUILayout.Label("Particle Count(" + system.particleCount + ")");
        GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
    else
        GUILayout.Label("No particle system found");

    GUI.DragWindow();
}
}
```

This might help you in playing,pausing and fully stopping your particle system from emitting particles.
Hope i helped.